# How to format a date in an Observable?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to filter a date column on a p-table but the data's date format doesn't seem to be recognized as a legitimate date, so the filter fails.  The object populating the table is an array in an Observable so I'm not sure where I could loop through it and reformat my date to something that works.

How can I format my date that lives in an Observable and return it to my html?

Edit:

Here's my code, at what point would I want to use map on the result of getItemsBySearch?

```
<div *ngIf="searchResults$ | async as results">

<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="results" ...>

searchResults$: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.searchResults$ = this.someService.getItemsBySearch(this.searchParams);
...}
```

Comment: You can use [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map). Your date should be either a string formatted in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *or* a [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) instance *or* a javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance.

Comment: Did you check the map operator in rxjs?  https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

Comment: I do know how to use map, but not in this situation.  I added code above but I'm not sure how to use map on an observable.